# Pseudo element :after and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have this markup:

```css
label.required:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="required">please enter your username</label>
```

I want to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to handle labels that are too long like so:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
}

label.required:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label class="required ellipsis">please enter your username</label>
```

The problem is that the `:after` pseudo element is cut off also, therefore no * appears

I want the label to look like this instead (with the `:after` pseudo element showing):

```
please enter your us... *
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. By setting the label `position: relative` and the position of the pseudo-element to `absolute`.

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
}

label.required:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label class="required ellipsis">please enter your username</label>
```

Comment: amazing! ill accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: or the `:after`, changing the pseudo element is not required

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right. However `position: relative;` for the label is required.

Comment: Guess you can't get around js there. You would have to check whether ellipsis was applied and that is not really the power of css.

Comment: this answers the question. accepted with thx. however, the positioning of the * is slightly off if there is no overflow. I've asked a new question on this new issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76884295/pseudo-element-after-and-ellipsis