# Pseudo element :after and ellipsis

Tags: html, css

From [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883424/pseudo-element-after-and-overflow-hidden). I've been given the following code, which displays a * after a required form label, even if the form label has an ellipsis.

It works perfectly when an ellipsis is displayed, but when no ellipsis is required, the positioning of the * is slightly off.

Is there a fix for this?

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 240px;
}
 
label.required:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="required ellipsis">long text works really really very really well</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="required ellipsis">short text * positioning is off</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you implement the ellipsis yourself I don't think there will be a way to do this, as you cannot act on a particular 'case' in CSS (as the overflow is always applied and the text-overflow is always an ellipsis even if its not displayed)

Comment: It doesn't actually "[work] perfectly when an ellipsis is displayed". If you look closely, it is actually overlapping the ellipsis too, it's just not as noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `position: absolute;`.
Wrap the text in a `<span>` and use `display: flex;`:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .3em;
  max-width: 240px;
}
 
.required:after {
  content: '*';
  flex: none;
  color: red;
}

.required span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label class="required">
  <span>long text works really really very really well</span>
</label>
<label class="required">
  <span>short text * positioning is off</span>
</label>
```

Comment: only problem is that the * is quite far away from the ellipsis - but prob best answer here thx

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To make the * next to the text, you can remove `column-gap: .3em;`

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with moving the * slightly to the right in both cases, you could add a span around your text and add the ellipsis class to it. This will allow you to move the * to the right without it being affected by `overflow: hidden;`

Like so:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 240px;
}
 
label.required:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -12px;
}

.ellipsis {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="required"><span class="ellipsis">long text works really really very really well</span></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="required"><span class="ellipsis">short text * positioning is off</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: If the `<label>` is the end of the screen, then * will go beyond it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub) after `<label class="required">`. Do not use the pseudo-element `::after`.

```html
<label class="required">Text</label><sup>&#10044;</sup>
```

**Details are commented in example.**

<sup>Comments noted with a dagger: `†` are required.</sup>
<sup>Any lengths in CSS may vary depending on how closely the example is followed.</sup>

```css
/**
 * Any font-size value assigned to <html> will be the default
 * reference value for 1rem for the entire page.
 * In this example 1.5ch is 1.5 width of a zero character: 0. 
 * The majority of lengths are in rems.
 */
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

legend {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

/* †
 * Assigned widths are possible.
 */
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 33rem; /* † */
  margin: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.35rem;
}

.tag {
  min-width: 3.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
}

/* † */
.required {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

sup {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.35em;
  left: -0.5em;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register a New Account</legend>
    <!--
      <div> is replaced by "label.group".
    -->
    <label class="group">
      <!-- 
        Assuming that the content occupies one line, another
        <label> and the form field <input> is added.
      -->        
      <label class="tag">Name: </label>
      <input name="username" required>
      <!-- †
        Wrap the text separately from the asterisk do not use
        the pseudo-element "::after".
      -->
      <label class="required"> A username is in the range of 5 to 15 alphanumeric characters.</label>
      <!-- †
        Add a <sup> after "label.required".
        For alternative asterisks refer to:
        http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/asterisk
      -->
      <sup>&#128950;</sup>
    </label>

    <label class="group">
      <label class="tag">Email: </label>
      <input name="useremail" type="email" required> 
      <label class="required"> A real email address.</label>
      <sup>&#128950;</sup>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```